# How to parse aws cli output using jq

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-elb

```
aws elbv2 describe-target-group-attributes \
    --target-group-arn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:123456789012:targetgroup/my-targets/73e2d6bc24d8a067
```

provides

```
{
    "Attributes": [
        {
            "Value": "false",
            "Key": "stickiness.enabled"
        },
        {
            "Value": "300",
            "Key": "deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds"
        },
        {
            "Value": "lb_cookie",
            "Key": "stickiness.type"
        },
        {
            "Value": "86400",
            "Key": "stickiness.lb_cookie.duration_seconds"
        },
        {
            "Value": "0",
            "Key": "slow_start.duration_seconds"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to fetch `deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds` from the output

I tried which works for this case when `deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds` appears on the second position.

```
aws elbv2 describe-target-group-attributes \
        --target-group-arn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:123456789012:targetgroup/my-targets/73e2d6bc24d8a067
 | jq -r '.Attributes[1].Value'
```

but for some target groups the `deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds` is placed at a different number.

How can I use jq to fetch `deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually use [JMESPATH](https://jmespath.org/) in the AWS CLI without needing to use `jq`:

```
aws elbv2 describe-target-group-attributes \
    --target-group-arn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:123456789012:targetgroup/my-targets/73e2d6bc24d8a067 \
    --query "Attributes[?Key=='deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds']|[0].Value" \
    --output text
```

JMESPATH was created by James Saryerwinnie, one of the authors of the AWS CLI. The [tutorial](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html) is well worth reading.

Comment: How can I remove quotes from output?

Comment: @cloudbud use `--output text`